# How to override the css of common html(ex: header html page) file included in another html file in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular6

[image]We are using header and footer as common in our code but in one page we need to add one css property for the common footer.

```
<app-footer>
  <footer class="mobile-footer">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </footer>
</app-footer>
```

so how can we override css of mobile-footer class from footer in another html page ex: customer page.
We have included the css file of footer in customer page in place of style urls also.

I have tried like accessing footer >.mobile-footer to override but it is not working. Can you please suggest solutions for this ?

Comment: do your customer page `body` or `wrapper` div have unique id ?

Comment: yes it has one unique id for body.

Answer (score 0):

You page has unique body `id`. You can apply styles to descendant element using your body `id`.

reference: [descendant-selector-css-selector](https://www.sitepoint.com/descendant-selector-css-selector/)

Example:

```
body#body-id footer>.mobile-footer{ ...}
```

use `!important` if needed.

Comment: can you inspect the footer and share sceenshot ?

Comment: i have added the image

Comment: Great it's help full. can you try `#view-offer footer.mobile-footer {background:#000 !important}` to test ?